# How to change the location of project created on intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My java project are by default created on default desktop, I want to change it to folder created on D drive. How should i do it?

I am copying the path of folder and trying to add it to location.

Comment: "I am copying the path of folder and trying to add it to location." and then what happened? Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

See the IntelliJ documentation, [*Open, close, and move projects*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/open-close-and-move-projects.html).

To quote:

1. In the **Project** tool window `⌘ 1`, right-click the root directory of your project and select **Refactor | Move directory** (`F6`).
2. In the dialog that opens, specify a new location for the project and click **Refactor**.

[image: screenshot of “Move Directory” dialog box]